# Get data from tabel [HTML] into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database, html

I would like to create a program that gets data from the play.eslgaming.com website and puts this into a database.

I already found out that the data I need is just in the raw code of the webpages. Like following:

```
<div id="round-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  <span class="teamstatus">Team: Evil Squirrels&nbsp;<small><i>(Attacker)</i></small></span>
  <table class="wot_stats">
    <tbody class="matchloser">
      <tr>
        <th>Tank</th>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Kills</th>
        <th>Dmg dealt</th>
        <th>Remain. HP</th>
        <th>Blocked dmg</th>
        <th>Time alive</th>
        <th>Shots fired</th>
        <th>Accuracy</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="tank">
            <img src="http://static-ptl-eu.gcdn.co/static/2.34.2/encyclopedia/tankopedia/vehicle/contour/ussr-object_140.png" class="icon-img">
            <em>U.S.S.R. Object 140</em>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="playername">
            <a target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer;" href="/worldoftanks/europe/wot/open/bronze-series/player/7176461">conchita_</a>
            <em>Conchita_</em>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2781</td>
        <td>Destroyed</td>
        <td>240</td>
        <td>07m 34s</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>50%</td>
```

And so on for each player each round 2 teams.

But the problem now is that I don't know how I get this information the easiest. As well I would like to put them into a database so I can make totals and monitor everything. I can program a bit C# so maybe there is a way to use this code.

I would like to know how I get the needed data from the webpages.

Comment: You can use classic ASP, Web Forms, MVC, or Web API with C# to get them onto your C# server. The last two are the current standards. Getting them into the database is another step. However, 80% of walk throughs, and 99% of books on any of those technologies will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: What you're trying to do is known as "screen scraping" - and you would be well advised to check the terms and conditions on the site to ensure they don't prohibit it.  If they don't, google on "Screen Scraping C#" and "HtmlAgilityPack".

Comment: You might not need to program anything. Google "web scraping applications"

Comment: So you want to store what's between `<table> </table>` tags? Are you interested in storing the raw html or are you interested in the actual data and storing this cleanly in a database table?

Comment: @D.Singh I would like to store the data in a database

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the AngleSharp project to do the scraping: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp